# Replace field values if value in list

Tags: r, dataframe

This is not a major issue, but something that annoys me.

in R I change the value of a field in one column, depending on the value of another column:

```
my_df[my_df$column1 == "ONE", 'column2'] <- "My text"
my_df[my_df$column1 == "TWO", 'column2'] <- "My text"
```

and so on

If I try to shorten to one line by adding:

```
my_df[my_df$column1 == c("ONE", "TWO"), 'column2'] <- "My text"
```

I get a warning message:
"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Is there an obvious way to do this without repeating the same line over and over?

Thanks for your help as always

Comment: did you mean `my_df[my_df$column1 %in% c("ONE", "TWO"), 'column2'] <- "My text"`? or using data.table: `library(data.table); setDT(my_df)[column1 %chin% c("ONE","TWO"), column2 := "My text" ]`

Comment: `my_df$column1 == c("ONE", "TWO")` should be `my_df$column1 %in% c("ONE", "TWO")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this.

The problem is the "`==`" operator.

You need to use "`%in%`" instead.

I.e. you don't want to ask if the value in column 1 equals `c("ONE", "TWO")` you want to ask if the value in column 1 is in the vector `c("ONE", "TWO")`.

So for your example:

```
my_df[my_df$column1 %in% c("ONE", "TWO"), 'column2'] <- "My text"
```

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution (assuming column2 already exists):

```
# sample df
my_df <- tibble(column1 = c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE"),
                column2 = c("a", "b", "c"))

# code
my_df %>% 
  mutate(column2 = replace(column1,
                           column1 %in% c("ONE", "TWO"), 
                           "My text"))
```